# How to remove white spaces before a table

Tags: white-space

I have the following code, but I am unable to remove the white space before the table even after using `\vspace{}` right after `\subsection{Nomenclature}`.

```
\section{Mathematical Modeling}

In this section we present the mixed integer linear programming (MILP) models that form the basis of decision-making and the subsequent computational testing. We first present a listing of notation used, then we present the UC-SOC model that corresponds to current practice / state-of-the art benchmark, and finally we present the new model being proposed in this paper. 


\subsection{Nomenclature}\label{nom}
  \vspace{-6.17mm}
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} l}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textit{A. Indices and Sets}}\\
\\
t & Index of time period, with  $t \in T$, the set of time periods.\\
s &Index of supplier, with $s \in S$, the set of suppliers .\\
j &Index of customer, with $j \in J$, the set of customers.\\
k &Index of attribute,  with $k \in K$, the set of attributes, $k$ = 1 denotes fixed payment,\\
 & $k$ = 2 denotes variable payment, $k$ = 3 denotes interruption ceiling.\\
%k =1 denotes fixed payments to customers,\\
%k =2 denotes interruption ceiling.\\ %need to find out 5_12
\ell_k &Index of level of $k^{th}$ attribute, with $\ell_k$ $\in$ $L_k$, the set of levels for attribute $k$.\\%need to find out 5_12
SOC &Set of SOC customers\\
\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Your example document is missing the `\begin{tabular}`. Please, make sure that the document is compilable (add the mandatory `\documentclass` and the relevant `\usepackage`s). Also, the `center` environment adds extra vertical spacing, you shouldn't use it in floats (e.g. `table` and `figure`), change to `\centering`. And you have two consecutive `\\ `, which will create an empty line in the table.

Comment: note that you are using `[H]` _by design_ `[H]` introduces large white space in documents as it disables the floating mechanism and the only reason that tables float is to avoid bad white space around page breaks.

Comment: unrelated but ` $k$ = 1 ` should be ` $k = 1$

Comment: Same goes for `$k$ = 1` and `$\ell_k$ $\in$ $L_k$` should be `$k = 1$` and `$\ell_k \in L_k$`.

Answer (score 3):

It's a common misunderstanding that a `tabular` has to go in a `table` environment. This is not true, it can go *anywhere*.

Some points to note before presenting the code.

1. No spaces around the slash
2. No space before a period
3. Most entries in the first column should be between `$` signs
4. `$k$ = 1` should be `$k=1$`
5. `$k^{th}$` should be `$k$\textsuperscript{th}` or,
   better, `$k$th`
6. `$\ell_k$ $\in$ $L_k$` should be a single formula `$\ell_k\in L_k$`

Here's the code, I just guessed a value for the width of the second column.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Mathematical Modeling}

In this section we present the mixed integer linear programming (MILP) 
models that form the basis of decision-making and the subsequent 
computational testing. We first present a listing of notation used, 
then we present the UC-SOC model that corresponds to current 
practice/state-of-the art benchmark, and finally we present the new 
model being proposed in this paper. 


\subsection{Nomenclature}\label{nom}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lp{.5\textwidth}}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textit{A. Indices and Sets}}\\
\\
$t$ & Index of time period, with  $t \in T$, the set of time periods.\\
$s$ & Index of supplier, with $s \in S$, the set of suppliers.\\
$j$ & Index of customer, with $j \in J$, the set of customers.\\
$k$ & Index of attribute,  with $k \in K$, the set of attributes,
      $k = 1$ denotes fixed payment, $k = 2$ denotes variable payment,
      $k = 3$ denotes interruption ceiling.\\
$\ell_k$ & Index of level of $k$\textsuperscript{th} attribute, 
           with $\ell_k\in L_k$, the set of levels for attribute $k$.\\
SOC & Set of SOC customers\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. The following solution worked. Please note that additional blank lines in the table (`\\`) were removed and `\centering` was used instead of center.

```
\subsection{Nomenclature}\label{nom}

\begin{table}[H]
   \centering
\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} l}%for math mode in table

\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textit{A. Indices and Sets}}\\
%\\
t & Index of time period, with  $t \in T$, the set of time periods.\\
s &Index of supplier, with $s \in S$, the set of suppliers .\\
j &Index of customer, with $j \in J$, the set of customers.\\
k &Index of attribute,  with $k \in K$, the set of attributes, $k= 1 $denotes fixed payment,\\
 & $k = 2$ denotes variable payment, $k = 3$ denotes interruption ceiling.\\
%k =1 denotes fixed payments to customers,\\
%k =2 denotes interruption ceiling.\\ %need to find out 5_12
\ell_k &Index of level of $k$\textsuperscript{th} attribute, with $\ell_k \in L_k$, the set of levels for attribute $k$.\\%need to find out 5_12
SOC &Set of SOC customers\\
\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```